# VBA - Check if cell contains certain texts. True/False. Fill Down

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that checks if Column C contains text. If it does then it will add a formula to Column A that checks if Column F contains either "V:" or "EC:", if so then returns True, otherwise False.

```
Sub FillDown()    
    Dim LastRowC As Long
    Dim VECFormula As String
    LastRowC = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    VECFormula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($F2, {"*V:*","*EC:*"})), "Yes", "No")"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Formula = VECFormula
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowC)
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like it would work except `{"*V:*","*EC:*"}`... never tried that.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?  BTW you can't put " inside a string in VBA without doubling it up to escape it, so `VECFormula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($F2, {""*V:*"",""*EC:*""})), ""Yes"", ""No"")"`

Comment: With the current formula i just get a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Tim Williams:

```
Sub FillDown()    
    Dim LastRowC As Long
    Dim VECFormula As String
    LastRowC = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    VECFormula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($F2, {""*V:*"",""*EC:*""})), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Formula = VECFormula
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowC)
End Sub
```

Comment: Note you can skip the `AutoFill` and just use `ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRowC).Formula = "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF($F2, {""*V:*"",""*EC:*""})), ""Yes"", ""No"")"`  - the formula will auto-adjust to the range you place it in.